# Getting a sum of timestamps in oracle sql (with fractional seconds)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, timestamp

Hello i tried to find a solution to sum timestamps from one columns. I found some post but i think in the end those solutions cuts off fractional seconds.

So i have a column in timestamp format with 6 fractional seconds like this '0001-01-01 00:01:23.652148'

I use this column to hold lap times in a race. Any idieas? :) Maybe i should use some other data type or format?

Plzz help! :) 
Much obliged.

Comment: How about storing the times as seconds and fractional seconds.

Comment: Well maybe i could but i have already have them stored in timestamps and i want to avoid altering the table :) But assuming it would be the easiest solution... how can i convert seconds to present the time as something like this   HH:MM:SS.FFFFFF ?

Comment: `0001-01-01` was a while ago. A timestamp is  date-time with fractional seconds, so I'm not sure what it means to add them together.

Comment: In my mind this problem is squarely on Oracle. The "rightest" data type for this kind of data *should* be INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. However, because aggregate functions such as SUM are not able to handle INTERVAL types yet (Hey, Oracle? What up wit' *DAT*?!?) the simplest solution is to convert your timestamp columns into NUMBERs, representing the number of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` type to store the data and then use a custom aggregation function to sum them. (However, if you have to use a `TIMESTAMP` data type then you can convert it to an `INTERVAL` by subtracting an epoch `TIMESTAMP` - i.e. `TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000`).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92c20e/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE LapTimes( time TIMESTAMP(6) )
/

INSERT INTO LapTimes ( time )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:01:23.652148' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:01:24.123456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:01:22.987654' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Custom Aggregation Function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IntervalAggregation AS OBJECT(
  value INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAggregation,
    value       IN     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY IntervalAggregation
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := IntervalAggregation( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAggregation,
    value       IN     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := value;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value + value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT IntervalAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT IntervalAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := ctx.value;
    ELSIF ctx.value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value + ctx.value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION IntervalSum( value INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND )
RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING IntervalAggregation;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT IntervalSum( time - TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000' ) AS totalLapTime
FROM   LapTimes
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92c20e/5/0)**:

```
|    TOTALLAPTIME |
|-----------------|
| 0 0:4:10.763258 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- INSERT INTO YOUR_OTHER_TABLE ( TotalLapTime )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           SUM( 
             EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM time ) * 60
             + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM time )
           ),
           'SECOND'
         ) AS TotalLapTime
FROM   LapTimes
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92c20e/5/1)**:

```
|            TOTALLAPTIME |
|-------------------------|
| 1-01-01 00:04:10.763258 |
```

Comment: Hmm. I belive you that this works, but i think it bit too much for my level of knowlege. Well of course i know what is a custom function i that i can create one myself. Altough i need something that dont include custom functions. It's because i'm making a project for school and we havent done this kind of think yet. I came up with something like this but now im stuck becouse i dont know how to convert interval to timestamp.... ;/ NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(
            extract( MINUTE FROM L_TIME)*60 + 
            extract( SECOND FROM L_TIME)), 'SECOND')

Comment: It gives good numbers. But next step is that i want to insert the sum to other timestamp columns ;)

Comment: It is bizarre to me that Oracle still hasn't got around to overloading aggregate functions for `interval` types. I don't know what can be taking them so long. I wrote [this](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/avg-and-sum-for-intervals.html) in 2004, expecting it to be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @Sławek Why are you using `TIMESTAMP`? You have a time interval so you should be using an `INTERVAL` data type rather than trying to fudge it as a time offset from 1st Jan 1AD.

Comment: @Sławek Updated with an alternate method - extracting the component parts of the time and converting it all to seconds before summing those and using `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to convert it to an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type to add to an (epoch) timestamp (which you could then insert into another table).